# Bluetooth connects, then disconnects very quickly

Tags: bluetooth

Today I tried connecting my Lumia 1020 through Bluetooth with my son's new Lego Mindstorms kit (EV3), and with my laptop.  In both cases, the phone connects, does the passcode business, and then disconnects after a few seconds.

Other Bluebooth things work OK; for instance, the laptop and the Mindstorms brick can connect to each other through Bluetooth just fine.

Is this a known bug in the Lumia 1020?  Is there a way to work around it or a setting I can change?  I was hoping to write a phone app to control his Mindstorms set, but I can't do that if Bluetooth won't stay connected.

Comment: Actually it looks like a WP behavior. The Windows Phone OS does not have all Bluetooth profiles and works better generally with accessories like earphones. For example to transfer files to a computer WP shows it's not connected until you start the transfer. The "Connected" state really means that it is doing something in that exactly moment.

Comment: Did my comment help you?

Comment: I have the same issue. I got a Microsoft Band 1 and I am having the same issue